# is it legal to show google map with directions in iphone application in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

is it legal to show google map with directions in iphone application in a UIWebView ?? i mean to say that can apple allow this ? can apple approve an application which shows google map with directions, inside UIWebView (Not with UIMapKit).

Comment: i want to use google map URl instead of MkMapKit framework because drawing a root between two points on MKMap whenever map position changed makes application slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**  Any questions?

Edit: I've used this approach in several published applications.  Note, though, that [`MKOverlayView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html) supports custom overlay drawing (as of iOS 4.0).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Google not only allow it, but they actively support it by providing you with the API.

Although they dont provide you with the actual code to convert it to iOS, many of the principles apply through their API on [this website](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)